# (python) make a file that has a name of a variable and an extension

Tags: python, file

I have a python code and i want it to make a file where it exports what the person wants(for a  order). I want to export to a file never created but i want it to be named (the costumer's name).txt for example John Smith.txt if they said there name was john smith.

My working code requires you to write your filename after python form.py 
for example python form.py test.txt would write what the user specified as their info
What i want is the file name to be their name and add the extension .txt
here is my code that works

```
from sys import argv 
file_name, script = argv
print "Hello I will now ask you for your information.\n"
print "What is your name (last first)?"
name = raw_input() 
print "Alright, what is your adderess? "
address = raw_input()
print "Phone Number"
number = raw_input()
print "Email" 
email = raw_input()
print "fax"
fax = raw_input()
print "Thank you now I will ask you for you vehicle information.\n"
print "Year"
year = raw_input()
print "Make"
make = raw_input()
print "Model"
model = raw_input()
print "Mileage"
mileage = raw_input()
print "vin number"
vin = raw_input()

print "Thank you processing information" 

target = open ("file_name", 'w')

target.write("Information for ")
target.write(name)
target.write("\n")
target.write("name: ")
target.write(name)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Address: ")
target.write(address)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Phone Number: ")
target.write(number)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Email: ")
target.write(email)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Fax: ")
target.write(fax)
target.write("\n")
target.write("\n")
target.write("Vehicle information")
target.write("\n")
target.write("Year: ")
target.write(year)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Make: ")
target.write(make)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Model: ")
target.write(model)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Mileage: ")
target.write(mileage)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Vin Number: ")
target.write(vin)
target.close()
print "Ok done saved info." 
print "\n"
```

Comment: [Working with File Objects](http://diveintopython.org/file_handling/file_objects.html)

Comment: What did you try? Show us what code you have so far. Ask us about the specific part that is giving you trouble. Don't just ask us to write it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking to create a simple file from a variable with a fixed extension:

```
myVar="Joe Smart"

x = open (myVar+".txt", "w")
x.write("hello")
x.close()
```

Creates `Joe Smart.txt` in the current directory. You'd want to do better error checking than I did.

Comment: Thanks your awesome works perfect i cant believe i didn't think of that now i feel stupid :p

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like mkstemp and/or add an order id to the filename so that 2 orders by John Smith.txt don't overwrite the same file.

Whenever you want to an unique file created atomicly you'll want to use the tempfile module.

```
import tempfile
filehandle, absolute_path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=user.full_name + ".txt")
```

Comment: qor72 made was shorter and does what i need better The overwrite isnt necessary to me but thanks anyway i voted up

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, have fun

```
def MakeFile(file_name):
    temp_path = 'C:\\Python3\\' + file_name
    file = open(temp_path, 'w')
    file.write('')
    file.close()
    print 'Execution completed.'
```

Then you can do: MakeFile('Daedalus.so')

Comment: sorry not what i was looking for